# Sphero Bluetooth Custom Implementation in Xamarin Android and MvvmCross

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin, mvvmcross

I would like to establish a connection between two android devices and send data from one device to another using mvvmcross. I want to use the sphero bluetooth implementation but I need to understand how the code works. I was hoping that someone can give me a starting point or a simple example based on Sphero implementation on how to achieve my goal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very quick search on google for "sphero xamarin" returns this project [BallControl](https://github.com/slodge/BallControl) project on github written by the author of mvvmcross (seriously Stuart where do you find the time!) as the first result!

This project not only does what you want on android, but also on iPhone, Windows store, windows phone and wpf!

Comment: Digging it now. Thanks.